# Replacing storyboard with XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode4.3

How can I replace storyboard with XIB?

While trying to create dynamically views and their controllers, I lost all advantages of the new storyboard. Now, when trying to remove it from the project, I created a new XIB with its own controller and replaced it in project settings:
[image]
Now, when trying to run the application, it crashes and the log shows me the following:

```
2012-04-08 14:50:16.567 Bazaart[11340:15203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x8c15c20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

Here is the code of: UIRootWindow:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIRootWindow : UIViewController
@end
```

And its corresponding implementation:

```
#import "UIRootWindow.h"
@implementation UIRootWindow

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

**EDIT:**
I've the window as suggested by Phillip (see below). But... the way I did it is not the best, it seems. Am I doing it right?

```
UIRootWindow *wnd = [[UIRootWindow alloc] init];
[wnd view];
[self setWindow:wnd.window];
```

Comment: Just a side note, for future compatibility you shouldn't start your own class names with `UI` or `NS` (imagine that in a future version of the SDK, Apple introduces a new class called `UIRootWindow`). Use your own prefixes, so you'd have something like `URKRootWindow`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put anything into the Main Interface field.  Instead, load your top-level controllers in the app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method and set the window's root controller there.

Application start-up assumes that a xib mentioned there has a File's Owner that is a UIApplication.  (Older templates used to do that and some sample projects still do.)

Comment: Thanks. It did work. Though, they way I attached the window is not optimal, it seems. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I suggest creating a brand new test app using the single view controller template (without a storyboard) and looking at how they set stuff up in the app delegate.  Basically you want your first controller (or its containing controller, if it has one) assigned to the delegate's `window.rootViewController`.

Comment: Thanks. This definitely answered my question. Should have thought about it myself.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is starting, each controller in your XIB is created based on the name of the class you've set. Then each property you've wired visually is set using KVC. The error is telling you that somewhere along this process, the 'view' property is incorrect.

I can think of two reasons why this might be happening:

- You don't have the right class set for your ViewController or another object in your XIB (in the 'Identity Inspector')
- You haven't correctly wired the connections. (In the 'Connections Inspector')

Either way, you can do a quick run-through of the settings in your XIB noting where the property 'view' is connected.